# Laravel Eloquent: Query with whereIn and orWhere very slow

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent, where-in

I am making the current query to retrieve an "`OV`" object with all his relationship. I recently added the function in `masters` and `wireless` to add a filter, but it introduce a very long delay.

Is there a mistake or an issue in the way that i use the whereIn and orWhere closes ?

Note: The `devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero` var is an array containing a list of macAddress

```
$data = Ov::with([
    'ovLicenses',
    'masters'=> function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
        $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero)->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','!=', '0');
    },
    'masters.licenses',
    'masters.equipment',
    'masters.slaveEquipments.equipment',
    'wireless'=> function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
        $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero)->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','!=', '0');
    },
    'wireless.licenses',
    'wireless.equipment'
])->where('ovId', '=', $ovId)->get();
```

With debugging with debugBar Laravel, i do the following request for wireless for example:

```
select * from `wirelessequipments` where `wirelessequipments`.`id_ov_foreign_key` in ('38') and `macAddress` in ('e8:e7:32:c1:e6:48', 'e8:e7:32:bc:b0:94', 'e8:e7:32:e4:8e:68', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:70', '00:e0:b1:fe:ef:a5', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:a4', '2c:fa:a2:10:79:74', 'e8:e7:32:b9:6d:1d', '00:e0:b1:ee:58:2d', '00:e0:b1:9d:2c:44', '00:e0:b1:b5:e6:00', '00:e0:b1:72:34:86', '00:e0:b1:fe:ee:8d', '00:e0:b1:79:53:52', '00:e0:b1:fe:f0:bd', '00:e0:b1:75:fa:8a', 'e8:e7:32:98:80:22', '00:e0:b1:75:00:8a') or `lastKnownUpAt` <> '0'
```

This request seems to be wrong because it return a wrong set of results.

Comment: Do you debug your queries somehow? (try [debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)). Debugging (or understanding) what is Eloquent ORM doing behind the scenes can help you out a lot. You might end up writing your own fast query, or you will optimise (cache on application layer) results somehow. Do you need all the data at once? Try limiting, selecting etc.

Comment: How big is the `$devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero` array?

Comment: @RossWilson Around 40 lines

Comment: Is there an index for `macAddress` and `lastKnownUpAt` ?

Comment: 40 rows shouldn't produce that much of a delay. Firstly, what field type are you using for `macAddress`? Also, do you have an index on the column?

Comment: Try to echo a `->toSql()` instead of the tail `->get()` function, and then run a `EXPLAIN` in your mysql to get any clue for the performance issue.

Comment: @apokryfos macAddress is a VARCHAR and there is no index in column

Comment: I update my post with an example or request extracted using Laravel debugger

Comment: Add indices. It will help.

Comment: What kind of indices?

Comment: Please provide a DESC from `wirelessequipments` table.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Laravel debugger u will see laravel eager loading runs two queries while you can do this in one with join which is much faster than Laravel's eager loading.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With Laravel debugger, i see multiple requests for each entry in my eloquent request. See my update please

Answer (score 0):

Covert whereIn into normal join will solve problem.
Use whereIn only with limited data range (second parameter).
Alternate of whereIn in case of interger only is whereIntegerInRaw which is really very fast.